# How to dynamically generate state variables based on the number of objects fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently trying to write React code that will fetch an object from an API and generate components with them. I am currently testing without using a fetch by creating a dummy object. The component I'm currently trying to generate is a checkbox that toggles between a checked and unchecked state. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to pass a toggle to my checkbox component. Usually I would just define toggles as individual state variables but since I am constrained to not know the size of the object I don't know how many checkboxes I will render and, thus, how many toggles I'd have to define.

This is the code I have been trying thus far to no avail. It is supposed to add toggles to the state variable "toggles" so that I have a list of booleans as long as my (in the future fetched) objects. Then I would created a checkbox for every object in "objects" and use the index so that each checkbox has a different toggle it can reference and they don't all check on the same click.

I think potentially there is an issue with addToggle because it doesn't seem to update anything when I console.log. Its also possible my entire approach is off base. (I also don't know if my "objects" variable is an object or pair of objects so sorry if my naming convention is off)

```
const [toggles, setToggles] = useState([]);

const objects = [
    {
        name: "dummy1"
    },
    {
        name: "dummy2",
    }
]

const addToggle = () => {
    setToggles([...toggles, false]);
    console.log(toggles) // output in console: [], []
}
  
useEffect(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
        addToggle();
    }
}, []);
```

This is what is what I'm trying to render in the return of my component.

```
{objects.map((object, index) => 
  <Checkbox toggle={toggles[index]} setToggle={setToggles} name={object.name} />
)}
```

This is the checkbox component I'm trying to use. (I wanted to avoid using input)

```
function RankingCheckbox({toggle, setToggle, name}) {
    if (toggle)
        return (
            <li className="dropdownItem" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>
                <span className="checkbox">
                    <AiOutlineCheck />
                </span>
                <span className="itemText">{name}</span>
            </li>
        );
    return (
        <li className="dropdownItem" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>
            <span className="checkbox" />
            <span className="itemText">{name}</span>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do your objects from your API call have unique ids?

Comment: I could design them to have unique ids, but the names are all by default unique so currently I wasn't planning on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is with trying to call `setToggles` within a loop:

```js
setToggles([...toggles, false]);
```

Each time `setToggles` is called, it doesn't immediately update your `toggles` state (it's only when your component eventually rerenders does the `toggles` state update), meaning that on the next iteration of your loop, `toggles` will still be an empty array. You can read [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) for more information on this.

While you can create an array of boolean values and associate them with each object in `objects` using an index, I'd suggest instead to create a new array of objects by mapping your original `objects` array. This new array is almost the same as the `objects` array you get from your API call but with an additional property to indicate if it's checked or not:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch call to API goes here, where you then get access to `objects`
  // then set your toggles state
  setToggles(objects.map(obj => ({ // map each object in objects to a new object ({ })
    ...obj, // that has all the properties of the current object
    checked: false // and has a new key called checked
  })));
    
}, []);
```

You would then `.map()` the `toggles` state. Note that you should also provide a [`key` prop](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) when mapping to JSX elements - that is unique and stable for each object in your array. Here I'm using your `name` property assuming that it's unique for each object and doesn't change):

```js
{toggles.map((toggleObj, i) => 
   <Checkbox key={toggleObj.name} toggle={toggleObj.checked} setToggle={() => updateToggle(i)} name={toggleObj.name} />
)}
```

When `setToggle` is called by the child component, it calls a function called `updateToggle()` given a unique identifier to find the object to update. Here I've provided the index, but you might use other methods such as an `id` if your objects have unique ids. The `updateToggle` function should use that unique identifier to update the object in the array. In the case of an index, that can be done using the [`.with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with) method:

```js
const updateToggle = (i) => {
  // Update the at index `i` to contain a new object with all the properties in the current one, but with the `checked` property flipped 
  setToggles(toggles => toggles.with(i, {
    ...togges[i],
    checked: !togges[i].checked
  }));
}
```

Remember, that in React, you should treat your state as read-only (ie: immutable) and not mutate it. That's why we're not using `toggles[i] = ...` above to update the object at index `i`, as that would mutate the original state and cause issues with rerendering. Instead, we're using `with()` ([you can also use `.map()`](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state), but `.with()` is a more modern alternative) which returns a brand new array, and the spread syntax `...` to copy the object and update it. Above I'm also passing a [state updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters) to the `setToggles()` function call to ensure that I'm getting the most up-to-date version of the `toggles` state before updating it.

Now that `setToggle` calls the `updateToggle` function, you can use it like so in your child component for the `onClick` prop:

```
onClick={() => setToggle()}
```

or even just:

```
onClick={setToggle}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! You did an awesome job breaking down where I went wrong and how to resolve my issues. It now works as intended. I was originally planning to map the checked values to my object but couldn't figure out how so your solution is even more in line with my preferred functionality.